# automatic snowflake email notifications for new onboarded users

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for an automated solution as onboarded email notifications as soon as new users onboard to Snowflake. I know now Snowflake supports the email functionality but not sure how to achieve this, and what specific steps are required to accomplish this requirement.

or is it really possible without using external tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a stored procedure to check the users created in result of "show users" output based on "created_on" column.

Store the timestamp of last run in any audit table and next time check users created after last timestamp from audit table. and send mail if any new users found.

Then schedule this stored procedure using a task. Based on your requirement, minimum being every minute (but better you can schedule once day for better credit consumption).

Below is sample code to start with, create stored procedure on it, update code to send mail accordingly.

```
-- Audit Tables
create table USER_MONITOR_AUDIT(CUT_OFF_TIMESTAMP datetime);
insert into USER_MONITOR_AUDIT values('2024-01-01');

-- Store proc body
begin

show users;
let res varchar := (select listagg(object_construct(*)::varchar,',') from(select "name","created_on","login_name","email" from table(result_scan(last_query_id()))
                        where "created_on">=(select max(CUT_OFF_TIMESTAMP) from USER_MONITOR_AUDIT)));
insert OVERWRITE into USER_MONITOR_AUDIT values(getdate());
if (:res<> '')
then 
    CALL SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL(
    '<integration_name>',
    '<email_address_1> [ , ... <email_address_N> ]',
    '<email_subject>',
    '<email_content>',
    [ '<mime_type>' ]
        );
end if;
    
return res;

end
```

Comment: thats what I was expecting, @aditya
will setup this and try to customize at per the env and requirement, Thanks

Comment: If you’re trying to email the user that’s been created then this won’t work, for the reasons already given

Comment: Correct this will not work if we want to email the new user(unless he manually verify the mail), But it'll work to email existing users(e.g. Admin) to mail list of all new users onboarded since last run. (I think there is some mis-understanding in exact requirment of intended recipients)

Comment: Ohh Okay Got you, will check if any work around is there for the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to notify users when they have been set up then this is not possible, as a user needs to confirm their email address within Snowflake before they can receive emails.

Otherwise, the process for sending emails is documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/email-stored-procedures)

Comment: Thanks, NickW, for the prompt reply, let me go through it and update you if thats works for me, regarding email ID's, yes we do add email ID's for users as login ID, not sure if that can be automatically picked up to send the notifications.

Comment: It's manual process to verify a user's email and can only be carried out by the user themselves via the UI - so there is no way of automating it